# Why can't I swap fixtures on collision in Box2D?

Tags: box2d, actionscript-3, starling

I'm trying to swap the fixtures associated with a body after colliding with a specific obstacle.

I can listen to the collision event by extending `b2ContactListener`. I tested it with a trace and it's working. My listener function in the main game class calls a `Player` method that makes the swap. But it's just not working.

The body is stored in `public var _body:b2Body;` in the `Player` class.

The method I'm calling goes like this:

```
public function changeFixture():void {
    var newShape:b2CircleShape = new b2CircleShape(1);
    var myFixtureDef:b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
    // Here I set density, friction, restitution, etc... Not important now...
    myFixtureDef.shape = newShape;

    _body.DestroyFixture(_oldFixture);
    _body.CreateFixture(myFixtureDef);

    // I know the method is called because this works
    trace('Yay! I'm working!');
}
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: I guess I found the answer. The CreateFixture and DestroyFixture methods are locked during callbacks. Just let me test it.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. You can't change your physics world during collision-callbacks. Store all the recorded collisions in a list and process the list of entities after the physics update.

Comment: Many thanks! Actually, now I've already taken another approach (worse than yours). But next time I already know what to do!

Comment: By the way, it's OK to answer your own question and mark it accepted. (It's useful for future readers with the same problem.)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the corrections. English is not my first language.

Comment: @bummzack, could you answer that one for me? I'm new to this community and can't answer my own question yet.

Comment: AFAIK Anyone can answer their own question regardless of rep.

Comment: Yes, but I'll have to wait for 8 hours and I'm pretty sure I'll forget to do it.

Comment: Forget about it. I just gained some rep and was able to answer now.

Comment: 22 hours 'till I can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all, everything was (almost) correct. The problem is you can't change the physics during callback. All I had to do was delay it to the next game cycle.